# Optimize eloquent queries

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have to get stats from database like this

```
$stats = [
    'products_count' => Product::where('status', 1)->count(),
    'last_year_products_count' => Product::whereYear('created_at', now()->subYear()->year)->count(),
    'last_year_order_items_count' => OrderItem::whereYear('created_at', now()->subYear()->year)->sum('quantity'),
    'order_item_unique_count' => OrderItem::distinct('product_id')->count(),
    'last_year_order_item_unique_count' => OrderItem::whereYear('created_at', now()->subYear()->year)->distinct('product_id')->count(),
    'order_products_avg' => OrderItem::avg('quantity'),
    'last_year_order_products_avg' => OrderItem::whereYear('created_at', now()->subYear()->year)->avg('quantity'),
];
```

I want optimize sql queries most as possible

Comment: As a first step you can index `status` and `created_at` columns.

Comment: Please provide the generated SQL and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comment is better to index your specific columns. You will need to add following logic in migration

For `products` table:

```
$table->index(['status', 'created_at']);
```

For `order_items` table:

```
$table->index(['created_at']);
```

For more information about database indexing in Laravel: [check out](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#indexes)

For more information about database indexing at all: [check out](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/indexing-in-databases-set-1/)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's bad idea use query for every field

Try get all data by 1-2 query and parse necessary information like:

```
$product = Product::where('status', 1)
    ->whereYear('created_at', now()->subYear()->year)
```

And this array look too complicated, mb you should decompose this array